# Не редактируются свойства в редакторе

Tags: android

Почему то не редактируются свойства элементов в Properties?
Это такой глюк или где-то стоит запрет на редактирование?
Стал разбираться - не редактируются свойства PlaintText. Остальные редактируются...
Как-то можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: eclipse/android studio/idea/свой собственный редактор?

Comment: Ну да, даже не написал какой редактор)))
Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

У меня в последнее время перестали редактироваться числовые свойства, и свойства с выбором из списка допустимых(типа gravity, width, height). Плюнул на Эклипс, установил Intellij IDEA, пользуюсь ей. Огромный ее плюс в том, что она может подключать дебагер в рантайме. То есть не обязательно запускать программу в дебаг-режиме, можно в любой момент перевести ее в дебаг режим. Советую перейти на нее...

Comment: какой кошмар! это просто проблема в Eclipse???